# How to convert .NET standard format string to Excel format string

Tags: .net, excel, format

I have an application that allows the user to create custom views of numeric data, and specify format strings used to display the data.  Typically users use .NET standard format strings such as N2, P1.

I now have a requirement to generate Excel exports, and want to format the exported data according to the user's preferences.

Is there anything "built-in" to convert a standard .NET format string to a custom format string that can be used in Excel.  E.g. "N2" => "#,##0.00"; "P1" => "#,##0.0 %", or do I have to roll my own?

Comment: have you made progress on this since you asked this question?  I really would like to find a quick solution to this, but I haven't found anything the last couple of days...

Comment: @JakeSmith - No progress, you'll have to roll your own I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I went through something similar, and sorry to tell you that basically you will have to do it your own parse.

Just a friendly advice, let me tell you that there is a catch if you are planning to export to a text file or similar (TXT/CSV/HTML) before importing into excel.

Excel will only read numbers correctly if he is able to "understand" the formatting (otherwise Excel will import as text or misread the number).

Example, lets say that .net uses a "," as the decimal point and excel use "." then the export you will probably misread the data.

That being said you should avoid formatting numbers if you plan to do a text file export that will be imported to excel. If you are generating your file directly from .net then you will have to do a manual parse of the strings (but shouldn't have any problems with misreading data).